# SQL Server: remove list entry from the string of another list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am sure that title is a bit confusing. Basically I have one table that has a column containing formation like "xx 123 Rg 43" and one that contains information like "Rg".. and if an entry from table 2's column is contained in the string contained in Table 1 then I need just  that entry removed.. leaving us with "xx 123  43"

Currently I am using:

```
update [Table1]
set [Col1] = case
                when (select * from [Table2] 
                      where charindex(' ' + [Col2] + ' ', [Col1]) > 0) is not null
                   then replace([Col1], (select * from [Table2] 
                                         where charindex(' ' + [Col2] + ' ', [Col1]) > 0), '')
                   else [Col1]
             end
```

And this works fine, but fails if this query

```
select * 
from [Table2] 
where charindex(' ' + [Col2] + ' ', [Col1]) > 0
```

returns more than 1 row with this error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

But I do need every match removed. Help!

Comment: Your fundamental problem is with your data structure.  Do not use strings to store lists of items.  SQL has a great data structure for lists.  It is called a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
update actual
set column1 = replace(column1, valueToReplace, '')
from TableWithActualData actual
inner join TableWithValuesToFind find
on actual.column1 like '%' + find.valueToReplace + '%';
```

See [SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d810d/4).

That said; this could have unpredictable behaviour... Suppose you have a value `catamaran` and you have logic to replace the words `cat` and `tamara`.  If you replace `cat` first you're left with `amaran`, which doesn't contain `tamara`.  If you replaced `tamara` first you're left with `can`, which doesn't contain `cat`.  What should the behaviour be in such scenarios?

The above code sort of avoids this; by only acting on the first match... However this means that even in scenarios where there are multiple valid replacements (e.g. replacing `cat` and `ran` in `catamaran`) you still won't get your expected result (`ama`), but rather the result will depend on which of `cat` or `ran` were found first (giving `amaran` or `catama` accordingly).

There's no way for you to specif icy this order either; the database will just operate on whichever results are returned first.

To avoid that, you're best off replacing one value at a time, in a predefined order... e.g. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/75ac9/6).

```
declare @valueToReplace nvarchar(256)

declare replaceValueCuror cursor for
select valueToReplace
from TableWithValuesToFind
order by priority

open replaceValueCuror

fetch next from replaceValueCuror
into @valueToReplace

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin

    update TableWithActualData
    set column1 = replace(column1, @valueToReplace, '')
    where column1 like '%' + @valueToReplace + '%'

    fetch next from replaceValueCuror
    into @valueToReplace

end

close replaceValueCuror

deallocate replaceValueCuror
```

Answer (score 0):

You seems want :

```
update t1
     set col1 = (case when exists (select 1 
                                   from t2 
                                   where charindex(t2.col2, t1.col1) > 0)
                                   )
                      then stuff
                      else t1.col1
                  end)
```